# How do I combine more ingredients during Alchemy?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to this page [*here*](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy) I should be able to combine up to four ingredients for each potion/poison. However, when attempting to make a potion, I found I can only combine up to 3 in one mix. Is there a way to increase the amount of ingredients per mix that I make, or is that page wrong?

Comment: The page you linked does not make the claim you assert.

Comment: @DavidB As you can see here: http://www.uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Skyrim:Alchemy&diff=787381&oldid=786739 at one point it did. They obviously removed it because it's not true, so my question is irrelevant anyway, but I just wanted to point out that I wasn't asking a question for no reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can only use three different ingredients per potion.  However, each ingredient has 4 potential effects.  Any effect which is shared by at least 2 of the ingredients will exist on the potion.  So you can end up with a number of effects if you have ingredients that share a lot, but you cannot exceed three ingredients.

Comment: Does it only add additional effects, or is it possible to boost a single effect (ie using three restore health ingredients)?

Comment: The strength of the potion (ie how much it heals) seems to be based solely on your alchemy skill.

Comment: So theoretically the most effects you can have on a potion is 6?

Comment: @Annan Since you have 12 effects total, and you need at least 2 of each, yes.  Although I doubt there are any ingredient sets that provide such a perfect matchup.  You would need something like 2 from A match 2 from B and the others 2 from C, and then B's remaining 2 match C's remaining 2.

Comment: 6 effects does seem theoretically possible

Answer (score 6):

6 effects is theoretically possible, but after running a java script to combine all possible sets of 3 ingredients, i found that there is no potion with 6 effects.

There are, however, 5 potions with 5 effects.

**EDIT:**
Since you ask, Holger, here they are :)
Theese are the 5 combinations, listed with value first
(calculated by values from this site: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects )

636
Glowing Mushroom,
Hanging Moss,
Glow Dust.

555
Creep Cluster,
Scaly Pholiota,
Mora Tapinella.

542
Eye of Sabre Cat,
Hanging Moss,
Bear Claws.

470
Blisterwort,
Jarrin Root,
Human Heart.

263
Daedra Heart,
Eye of Sabre Cat,
Silverside Perch.

As you can see, not all of them are great value in spite of having 5 effects. The first one is still the most valueable potion you can create, even considering the huge boost you get from creating a Fortify Health potion using Giant's toe.

The second most valuable potion is this one (which only has 3 effects):

614
Giant's Toe,
River Betty,
Large Antlers.

Comment: Could you post the answers? :)

Comment: The potions can be much stronger and _more valuable_ depending on your alchemy skill, perks and enchantments. Also, I think there is only one Jarrin root in the whole game, so it's not that relevant.